# Scrolling vertically and horizontally in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` (params = MatchParent,MatchParent) as my content view.

The `RelativeLayout` contains a `ScrollView` (params=Wrap_Content, Wrap_Content).

The `ScrollView` then contains a `LinearLayout` ( no params, set vertical orientation).

To the `LinearLayout` I'm adding "myrows".

Each myrow is made up of another `LinearLayout` (no params, horizontal orientation) which contains a `SpannableString` which contains equally spaced/padded numbers.

The result is a vertically scrollable table, and looks ok.  The problem is that if I run it on a smaller device, the `SpannableString`s extend out of the screen.

On the smaller screen I want the text to be large enough to read, and so I need to be able to scroll horizontally as well to see the part of the `SpannableString` which has extended beyond screen.  I have tried a couple of solutions already. One was to put the vertical `ScrollView` inside a horizontal `ScrollView` and capture the xy etc...but people mentioned this is dangerous. I don't want the strings to wrap.  I can't use a dropbox etc...to show the beyondcreen values. It has to be a flat table with text large enough to read, I can't eliminate any of the string length.

I can make it instead a horizontal `ScrollView` and put a page up/down button but it won't work as smooth as it does now. Could I put a `ListView` inside a horizontal `ScrollView` and be able to scroll in both directions?

Any other ideas for this?  Is there a scroll bar I can put at the bottom that scrolls the screen horizontally where it only captures your finger touch on the bar itself?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's just a clump of text then sounds like you could use a textView and just wrap_content. 

Trying to draw something that looks like a table? then why not use a ListView?

Could you give us more detail on like your desired result?

Comment: My desired result is on the screen of the device i need to show a large table, like with msexcel.  The table is too wide to fit on smaller devices.  I want to be able to slide the view horizontally to see the rest of the table, while still being able to scroll up and down since there are over 100 rows.  The rows are dynamically added.

Like I said above, the rows are too wide to fit on the screen of smaller devices.  I don't want the rows to wrap around (i.e. getting to the end of the screen and then going to a new line), they have to go off screen.

Comment: Imagine using msexcel, the cells are full all the way to column AX, obviously that's off the screen, but you can scroll right to see all the data, that's what i need to do.

Comment: OK, I experimented with putting a ListView inside a horizontalScrollView.  It seems to work.  However the width of the ListView is only as wide as the first row in the list view, which is not a problem for me since all my rows are the same width.

Comment: I figured out how to do this using a custom GridView that can do the horizontal scrolling without breaking the ListAdapter and vertical scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution which works great.  Create a custom gridView with the following overrides.  I also created a scrolling header which follows the scroll of the gridView.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
    getMaxLeftScroll();
    myLastX = ev.getX();
    myLastY = ev.getY();
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev){

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final float x;
    final float y;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // This handles Scrolling only.
            x = ev.getX();
            y = ev.getY();

            final int deltaX = (int) (myLastX - x);
            final int deltaY = (int) (myLastY - y);

            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {

                if( (iCurrentLeftScroll+deltaX) > 0 &&
                        iCurrentLeftScroll+deltaX < iMaxLeftScroll) {
                    scrollBy(deltaX, 0);
                    //Listener and call the method here to scroll the header
                    mScrollChangeListener.onGridViewScrolled(deltaX);

                    iCurrentLeftScroll+=deltaX;
                }  //Scrolled by some value

                // Close to right edge within 10? Smooth Scroll remaining small distance if not already there
                else if(deltaX > 0 && (iCurrentLeftScroll<iMaxLeftScroll)) {
                    if ((iMaxLeftScroll - iCurrentLeftScroll) < 10) {
                        scrollBy(iMaxLeftScroll-iCurrentLeftScroll, 0);
                        mScrollChangeListener.onGridViewScrolled(iMaxLeftScroll-iCurrentLeftScroll);
                        iCurrentLeftScroll = iMaxLeftScroll;
                    }
                }
                // Close to left edge within 30? Smooth Scroll remaining small distance if not already there
                else if(deltaX < 0 && (iCurrentLeftScroll>0)) {
                    if ((iCurrentLeftScroll) < 10) {
                        scrollBy(iCurrentLeftScroll*-1, 0);
                        mScrollChangeListener.onGridViewScrolled(iCurrentLeftScroll*-1);
                        iCurrentLeftScroll = 0;
                    }
                }

                //left and right are subjective
                if(iCurrentLeftScroll == iMaxLeftScroll)
                    iScrollStatus = SCROLLED_FULL_LEFT;
                if(iCurrentLeftScroll == 0)
                    iScrollStatus = SCROLLED_FULL_RIGHT;
                if( (iCurrentLeftScroll > 0) && (iCurrentLeftScroll < iMaxLeftScroll) )
                    iScrollStatus = 0;
                Log.d(TAG," Scroll Status " + String.valueOf(iScrollStatus) );
                Log.d(TAG," MaxLeftScroll " + String.valueOf(iMaxLeftScroll) );
                Log.d(TAG," Current Left Scroll " + String.valueOf(iCurrentLeftScroll) );

            }

            myLastX = x;
            myLastY = y;

            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```